# QCAR::Image to UIImage - CoreGraphics and retain crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, vuforia

I'm using Vuforia , trying to get pixels from camera instance and convert to UIImage

```
- (UIImage *)createUIImage:(const QCAR::Image *)qcarImage
{
    int width = qcarImage->getWidth();
    int height = qcarImage->getHeight();
    int bitsPerComponent = 8;
    int bitsPerPixel = QCAR::getBitsPerPixel(QCAR::RGB888);
    int bytesPerRow = qcarImage->getBufferWidth() * bitsPerPixel / bitsPerComponent;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault | kCGImageAlphaNone;
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;

    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, qcarImage->getPixels(), QCAR::getBufferSize(width, height, QCAR::RGB888), NULL);

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(width, height, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);
    CGImageRef imageRefRetain = CGImageRetain(imageRef);
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRefRetain];

    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    return image;
}
```

After getting the image, I add it to a mutable array.

Once retrieving the image from the mutable array, I get crash on every method
i.e.

```
UIImageView setImage:
```

or even calling

```
NSData* comppressedData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,1);
```

The only way to make my app not to crash is adding the following

```
- (UIImage *)createUIImage:(const QCAR::Image *)qcarImage
{
    ...
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRefRetain];

    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    NSData* comppressedData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,1);
                    UIImage* jpegImage = [UIImage imageWithData:comppressedData];
    return jpegImage;
}
```

So i think it's an issue related to the CGImageRef getting released.
I really need to understand what's going on and why the image ref isn't valid after existing the method.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `qcarImage` is going out of scope and taking the raw image data with it. Copy the image buffer and provide that to the `CGDataProviderRef`

```
NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithBytes:qcarImage->getPixels() 
                                    length:QCAR::getBufferSize(width, height, QCAR::RGB888)];
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, imageData.bytes, imageData.length, NULL);
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(width, height, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);
//This was leaking memory, commenting out
//CGImageRef imageRefRetain = CGImageRetain(imageRef);
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
```

Answer (score 0):

The central issue is that creating the CGImageRef using a wrapping CGDataProvider does not copy the data it just wraps the underlying base address which will go away when Vuforia decides it should. It is very important to note that copying the data will have a significant performance hit.

#### QCAR::Image to CGImageRef

Note: I avoid the mixing of Obj-C in this method.

```
CGImageRef CGImageCreateWithQCARImage(const QCAR::Image *image, float rotation)
{
    CGImageRef quartzImage = NULL;

    if (image) {
        QCAR::PIXEL_FORMAT pixelFormat = image->getFormat();

        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = NULL;
        switch (pixelFormat) {
            case QCAR::RGB888:
                colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
                break;
            case QCAR::GRAYSCALE:
                colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
                break;
            case QCAR::YUV:
            case QCAR::RGB565:
            case QCAR::RGBA8888:
            case QCAR::INDEXED:
                OARLogError("Image format conversion not implemented.");
                break;
            case QCAR::UNKNOWN_FORMAT:
                OARLogError("Image format unknown.");
                break;
        }

        if (colorSpace != NULL) {
            size_t bitsPerComponent = 8;
            size_t width = image->getWidth();
            size_t height = image->getHeight();
            const void *baseAddress = image->getPixels();
            size_t totalBytes = QCAR::getBufferSize(width, height, pixelFormat);

            CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault | kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast;
            CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;

            size_t bitsPerPixel = QCAR::getBitsPerPixel(pixelFormat);
            size_t bytesPerPixel = 4;
            size_t bytesPerRow = image->getStride();

            CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,
                                                         width,
                                                         height,
                                                         bitsPerComponent,
                                                         bytesPerPixel * width,
                                                         colorSpace,
                                                         bitmapInfo);

            CFDataRef dataRef = CFDataCreate(NULL, (const UInt8 *)baseAddress, totalBytes);
            CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(dataRef);
            CGImageRef intermediateImage = CGImageCreate(width,
                                                         height,
                                                         bitsPerComponent,
                                                         bitsPerPixel,
                                                         bytesPerRow,
                                                         colorSpace,
                                                         bitmapInfo,
                                                         provider,
                                                         NULL,
                                                         false,
                                                         renderingIntent);

            CGFloat halfWidth = width / 2.f;
            CGFloat halfHeight = height / 2.f;
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, halfWidth, halfHeight);
            CGContextRotateCTM(context, rotation);
            CGContextScaleCTM(context, -1.f, -1.f);

            CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(-halfWidth, -halfHeight, width, height), intermediateImage);
            CGImageRelease(intermediateImage);

            quartzImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
            CGContextRelease(context);

            CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
            CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
            CFRelease(dataRef);
        }
    }

    return quartzImage;
}
```

#### CGImageRef to UIImage

Then back in Obj-C land.

```
QCAR::Image qcarImage = ...; 
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithQCARImage(qcarImage);
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

You may ask yourself why allocate the context bitmap (`NULL`) rather than wrap the existing bytes (`baseAddress`)? The answer is you can't create a context with a non-power of 2. 24 bits per pixel is not allowed and you'll get a null context if you try to set the bytesPerRow to be 'width in pixels' * '3 bytes per pixel.' So we create the Image, then draw it into the context restoring the alpha channel.